# Why transactions are not rolling back in Spring while running with Junit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I am trying to test my service class with Junit with Rest Template.My Service have multiple calls to the database so i marked it as a @transaction to make those calls as single transaction.But the thing is if any one of the calls failed to excetued or any one throws an exception, the earlier comitted calls should be rollback.But the earlier comitted transaction are not rolling back.

```
 @Transactional
    class A
    {

    @Autowired
    B object

    object.someMethod()//this method has logic to save the data

    object.someOtherMethod()//this method will throws an Exception
    }
   @Transactional
   class B
  {
     someOtherMethod()
      {
        //here it will throw an exception
      }
  }
```

Here is my partial spring configuration file

```
    <tx:annotationdriven ref=transactionManager/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean"/>
        </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dbDataSource" />

<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
            </property>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>              
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop> 
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Have you checked your spring configurations. Chances are that you have autocommit set to true in datasource file.

Comment: @vineethsivan Don't talk rubbish. If an exception is thrown, the transaction is rolled back by default. This can be changed in the `@Transactional` annotation, but autocommit has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

How did you run your JUnit test? Did you run it with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner like what is documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/testing.html)? **If you are not, chances are your bean will not be weaved with transaction managed by Spring.**

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.